# Suma y recorrido de un array

Tags: java

Tengo este programa el cual debe de sumar 2 números de un array y me debe de decir cuales son los 2 número dentro del array que me da esa suma, *solo debe mostrar una impresión con los números y en mi código me hace la impresión en consola 2 veces*, agrego el código:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        int[] myArray = {3,5,2,5,8,9};
        
        for (int i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < myArray.length; j++) {
                if (myArray[i] + myArray[j] == 5) {
                    System.out.println("el primer número es: " + myArray[i] + " El segundo número es: " + myArray[j]);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Este es el resultado que a mí me arroja en la consola:

> ```
> el primer número es: 3 El segundo número es: 2
> el primer número es: 2 El segundo número es: 3
> ```

Pero solo quiero que lo haga una vez ya que son los mismos números.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Estás recorriendo el array con 2 bucles for por lo que habrán dos coincidencias.

- La primera será:
  `3 + 2`
- La segunda será:
  `2 + 3`

Si no necesitas que se siga verificando que haya otra coincidencia donde un par de números den la suma de 5, simplemente podrías colocar un "flag" para bucles anidados (le llamaré flag_bucle_anidado de ejemplo) para controlar la estructura completa de ambas bucles y luego de imprimir por consola el resultado hacer un break de este:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        int[] myArray = {3,5,2,5,8,9};
        flag_bucle_anidado:
        for (int i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < myArray.length; j++) {
                if (myArray[i] + myArray[j] == 5) {
                    System.out.println("el primer número es: " + myArray[i] + " El segundo número es: " + myArray[j]);
                    break flag_bucle_anidado;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Resultado:

```
el primer número es: 3 El segundo número es: 2
```

Answer (score 1):

Usa j para explorar los numeros que hay despues de la posicion i

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        int[] myArray = {3,5,2,5,8,9};
        for (int i = 0; i < myArray.length-1; i++) {//explora del primero al penultimo
            for (int j = i+1; j < myArray.length; j++) {//explora despues de i hasta el ultimo
                if (myArray[i] + myArray[j] == 5) {
                    System.out.println("el primer número es: " + myArray[i] + " El segundo número es: " + myArray[j]);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```